# Python Parsing XML Response

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP response which I am trying to parse with `ElementTree`

```
    doc = ET.parse(response_xml)
    for cust in doc.findall('.//{http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}Content'):
        custnumber = cust.findtext('{http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}CustomerNumber')
        custfname = cust.findtext('{http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}FirstName')
        custlname = cust.findtext('{http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}LastName')
    return custnumber, custfname, custlname
```

I am trying to get the information out of the response and I keep getting the following error:

`No such file or directory`

Does the `response_xml` need to be saved to a file before I can parse it? Why can't I just use it from memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ET.parse()` needs a file name. You might want to try `ET.fromstring()` instead.